streamlit st_pages doesn't work in docker container
The side menu rendered by st_pages in my streamlit app works on my host, but when I run it in a docker container, it doesn't and falls back to the streamlit menu. It doesn't give any errors - just does nothing. Why isn't st_pages working in docker? Do I need to install anything in addition to st_pages? Importing st_pages doesn't throw an error inside the docker.
import streamlit as st
from st_pages import Page, show_pages, hide_pages
import os

abs_path = os.path.abspath(__file__).strip("Home.py")
show_pages(
    [
        Page(os.path.join(abs_path, "Home.py"), "Home", ""),
        Page(os.path.join(abs_path, "pages", "first.py"), "First Page", ""),
    ]
)
st.header("Home Page")

Dockerfile
FROM python:3.12

# Install required python libraries
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy code
COPY src /home/viz_tools

EXPOSE 8080
CMD streamlit run /home/viz_tools/Home.py --server.port=8080

[Update based on comment from @KamilCuk]
Tried to cd into /home/viz_tools and then running streamlit, but that gives an error
RUN cd /home/viz_tools/
CMD streamlit run Home.py

and
CMD cd /home/viz_tools && streamlit run Home.py

both of which don't even run streamlit and give the error
Usage: streamlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET [ARGS]...
Try 'streamlit run --help' for help.

Error: Invalid value: File does not exist: Home.py


os.path.abspath(__file__).strip("Home.py") os.path.join(abs_path, "Home.py") why are you doing this? Just Page("Home.py"

Because the relative path depends on where you run streamlit run from, and I can't seem to cd into the folder to run streamlit from where Home.py is, in my docker container.

it's cd /home/viz_tools && streamlit run Home.py. One & runs in the background. Check a linux shell introduction.

My bad - that was a typo. Fixed it

You have the error. So what have you tried to debug it? Add ls to the call, check tge files, stat the file, check permissions, check your user, etc, run container inteactively and check. The error you posted is clear, there is no such file.

I am honestly stumped - if there was an error message of some sort, I could work with it. But here, there is no error message. st_pages simply doesn't seem to do anything. The problem isn't with running streamlit (unless you are saying that the way I am running streamlit is what's causing st_pages to not even work)

First cd into /home/viz_tools, then run streamlit. Current working directory is important.

Tried that and that doesn't work either. I will add to the main conversation.
